# Custom key value pairs in push message

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am currently using the Urban Airship service to send Push Messages and looking at moving to Parse.com.

In Android, one can supply a set of data using key value pairs which can be accessed once the message is tapped.

Using Parse, is it possible to include this custom payload when sending to iOS and Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Here's an example of a Parse push with arguments, in CloudCode.

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
    data: {
        alert:  "Notification message",
        keyOne: "First value",
        keyTwo: "Another value"
    }
},{
    success: function() {
        // Push was successful
    },
    error: function(error) {
        throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
    }
});
```

Then you can access the data on the device receiving the Push.